# Unicode character won't align to center of button

Tags: html, css, unicode

After using a unicode for a button, I've noticed that the unicode character is not properly aligned to the center (both horizontally & vertically) of the button. I'm not sure why this is happening when I used `padding: 0;`

```css
.btn{
  background-color: #868f98;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 20%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">&#9776;</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `line-height` to `60px` on your .`btn` rule will center the character.

```css
.btn{
  background-color: #868f98;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 20%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">&#9776;</button>
```

Comment: but it isn't centered that way... (?) at least not in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

apparently that symbol character is not in the vertical center of its line. (It *is* horizontally centered, though) So you just have to try around with a padding-bottom until you find the right value:

```css
.btn{
box-sizing: border-box;
vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #868f98;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 20%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0 0 0.24em 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">&#9776;</button>
```